# Fillyby function not reading procedure result

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, tableadapter, xtrareport

Im rendering a gridview using DevExpress.XtraReports on visual basic. The grid populates based on a tableAdapter. To fill the tableAdapter I use the Fillby function as follows:

```
TableAdapter1.Fillby(dataset, parameter1, parameter2)
```

When I run on sql server manager the procedure that fills the dataset, using the same parameters I see the code is sending, the procedure returns several rows, but the code seems to return nothing.

Why is the code not reading the returned values?

Comment: I think we will need to see the other parts of the code that set up the TableAdapter to have a better chance to help you

Comment: Firstly, you should never have a method named `FillBy`. You're supposed to provide a logical, descriptive name for that method, as you should every method. When you create a table adapter, the default methods to execute the `SELECT *` query are named `Fill` and `GetData`. When you add a new query with a filter, you're supposed to name the method appropriately, if you filter by `ColumnX` in the `WHERE` clause then the methods should be named `FillByColumnX` and `GetDataByColumnX`.

Comment: As for the issue, you need to debug your code and you should have already done so before posting here. There's no "seems". You need to look and find out. That `FillBy` method returns a number and that is the number records retrieved. Look at it. Is it zero? I not then you've just asked us a question about a problem that doesn't exist and the actual problem is in the displaying of the data afterwards. If it is zero then the simple fact is there is no data in the database that matches your criteria so either your database is wrong or your criteria are wrong. We can't tell you more than that.

Comment: The issue was a typo in the first parameter name